# Flutter edit existing pdf Dart

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

Here I am after a few hours of research, I would like to know if there is any way I can add text to a PDF in my assets, and then be able to download it to the user's phone with Flutter?

Comment: You can use html to pdf convertor, so you will have already defined html which you will edit and when there will be need for pdf you will simply generate pdf from it with flutter_html_to_pdf: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_to_pdf